# Aligning an image next to an unordered list horizontally

Tags: html, css, web, navigation

So i'm trying to have an image alongside an unordered list (image acting as home button for the navigation) however the actual list keep shifting down, when I want it to be next to the home image. Any ideas on how to fix this?

This is what's happening: [Image not aligned with the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOjFC.png)

```
<div id="navigation">
<a href="#"><img src="images/home_button.png" alt="Image representing a home icon" id="home_button"></a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Phantom of the Opera</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">The Lion King</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Wicked</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
        <li><a href='#'>Location</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

```
#navigation {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2F4E6F;
}

#navigation li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
    color: #7c7f84;
    border-bottom: solid black 2px;
}

#navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

#home_button {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `display: flex` to the parent and it will put them in a flex row.

```css
#navigation {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #2F4E6F;
  display: flex;
}

#navigation li a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

#navigation li a:hover {
    color: #7c7f84;
    border-bottom: solid black 2px;
}

#navigation li {
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 10px;
    background-color: red;
}

#home_button {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigation">
  <a href="#"><img src="images/home_button.png" alt="Image representing a home icon" id="home_button"></a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Phantom of the Opera</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">The Lion King</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wicked</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Bookings</a></li>
    <li><a href='#'>Location</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `float` property in your CSS. This will allow the elements to be displayed alongside eachother.

Add the line `float:left;` to the CSS of `#home-button`, and add `float:right` to your unordered list.